# listings interfering with babel

Tags: listings, babel

Consider this script:

```
\documentclass{article}                                                                                                                                                                            
%\usepackage[latvian]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}                                                                                                                                                                                          
\end{document}
```

I get an error

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg))
(./latvianpres.aux)

! LaTeX Error: No counter 'chapter' defined.
```

if I uncomment the line

```
%\usepackage[latvian]{babel}
```

What is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: latvian defines \thechapter and this confuses listings. I would say it is a babel-latvian bug. Notify the author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a bug in Latvian babel (as Ulrike Fischer said). The file `latvian.ldf` (loaded by `babel`) defines `\thechapter`:

```
\def\thechapter{%
  \ifx\chapter\undefined\relax\else
  \arabic{chapter}.\fi}
```

independently if you are using a class with or without `\chapter`s. Later on, `\AtBeginDocument` `listings` defines the `lstlisting` counter conditionally if `\thechapter` is defined:

```
\newcounter{lstlisting}[chapter]
```

or if not:

```
\newcounter{lstlisting}
```

When `\thechapter` exist (it does, when `latvian.ldf` is loaded), `listings` tries to hook the `lstlisting` counter to the `chapter` counter, which does *not* exist and you get the error.

You can work around it with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latvian]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\let\THEchapter\thechapter
\let\thechapter\relax
\begin{document}
\let\thechapter\THEchapter

\end{document}
```

Comment: :-/ Not that `latvian.ldf` should not be fixed (there is no "local" maintainer, and therefore I'm maintaining it in the sense I'm fixings bugs), but there is clearly a bug in the `listings` side, too: if the counter `chapter` is used, this is exactly what must be tested, and not another macro.

Comment: @JavierBezos You're right, it really doesn't make much sense :/