# No counter 'chapter' defined. \begin{document}

Tags: formatting, undefined

Upon trying to insert Python code in my LateX document I ran into corresponding error message.

Code, which recreates the error message and contains only the most vital parts of my documents:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latvian]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
    language=Python,
    aboveskip=3mm,
    belowskip=3mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
    numbers=none,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    tabsize=3
}

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper,
    top=2.5cm,
    bottom=3cm,
    left=3cm,
    right=3cm,
    headheight=0.75cm,
    footskip=1.5cm,
    headsep=0.75cm,
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
    #Hello, world!
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aparently, this is related to `\usepackage[latvian]{babel}`.

Comment: Any alternatives?

Comment: Would you agree that your question is a duplicate to the following one? [listings interfering with babel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/463574/134144)

Comment: Worked! Thank you kind sir!